# Remotely start recording on 60D with Yongnuo RF-602's

Tags: video, canon-60d, remote, wireless-triggers

I have a Canon 60D and Yongnuo RF-602 wireless flash triggers/shutter release.

If I connect the receiver via a cable to the camera, I can use the transmitter to remotely take a picture. When I put the camera in video mode, I thought that this would trigger the camera to start recording, but instead it takes a single picture with two vertical grey bars.

How do I remotely start video recording on my 60D using RF-602's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I found on page 177 in the manual for Canon 60D:

[image: Picture of an excerpt of text from Canon's 60D manual.]

While this certainly works with the Canon's radio remote, I have not actually tested it with the Yongnuo. My guess is, the signal from the trigger simulates the 'immediate shooting' signal emitted by Canon's own triggers, and that's why you are only able to shoot stills with it.

As far as I can tell, Yongnuo 602s don't have any 'delayed' mode, that would let you simulate timed shutter release. So I think what you want to do may be impossible.